# cannot write Awkward Array type to ROOT file

Tags: uproot

I'm new to uproot lib and just a user.
I want to write the string type into root file, but the error happens as below:

Error:
`TypeError: cannot write Awkward Array type to ROOT file:    46 * string`

**Aim**: I want to extract some information from 10 root files via a algorithm and merge them into one root file. I stored these information into a list.

The root file and the code can be found here[GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6-Ug-uq3sHMwsY9ISJj8K2Dw9ssuLlF/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a32KQw30iLBv_H9qWcNUEsBAfEDOSTVM/view?usp=sharing)

Does someone know how to solve this problem? I would be very grateful if someone could solve this difficult problem.

Best,
Jing (jing.zhang@univ-brest.fr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to write strings was added in [PR #940](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot5/pull/940) (Oct 2023), which is in release [5.0.13](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot5/releases/tag/v5.0.13), [5.1.0](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot5/releases/tag/v5.1.0), and following. Here's a demo:

```py
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> import uproot
>>> strings = ak.Array([f"str{i}" for i in range(46)])
>>> print(strings.type)
46 * string
>>> with uproot.recreate("output.root") as file:
...     file["tree"] = {"branch": strings}
...
```

Then, restart Python (to prove that it's really in the file) and read it back:

```py
>>> import uproot
>>> with uproot.open("output.root") as file:
...     strings = file["tree"]["branch"].array()
... 
>>> print(strings.type)
46 * string
>>> strings
<Array ['str0', 'str1', 'str2', ..., 'str44', 'str45'] type='46 * string'>
```

So you should be able to just upgrade Uproot and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid reply and your answer inspired me a lot. In fact, the root file does not allow the array like [ [list0], [list2], ... [list9 ] ], when I do the merge. So I changed the way to do the merge. That is I replaced the list.append() method to list.extend(), so the merged list is [list0, list1, list2, ... list9]. It works both in a string array or a number array.